# SQL Update, subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-update

```
Timezones
---------
-AreaCode varchar
-Timezone varchar

Contacts
--------
-Phone    varchar
-Timezone varchar
```

Everything is populated except `Timezone` in the Contacts table, so I want to lookup the timezone for each phone number and update the contacts. Here's what I tried to do, but `MySQL` gives

> Error 1242 Subquery returns more than one row

For each timezone (0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5), I execute this update:

```
update contacts 
set contacts.timezone = '-1' 
where left(contacts.phone,3) = (Select timezones.areacode 
                                from timezones 
                                where timezones.timezone = '-1');
```

Comment: Well, have you validated that there really *is* only one time zone for each ID?

Comment: I just checked, there are no duplicate areacodes in the timezones table

Comment: I asked about duplicate `timezone` values, not duplicate areacodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery returns more than one row. Just replace "=" with "IN" to handle this issue:

```
update contacts 
set contacts.timezone = '-1' 
where left(contacts.phone,3) in (Select timezones.areacode 
                                from timezones 
                                where timezones.timezone = '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an inner join on the update, or a subquery:

```
update contacts 
set contacts.timezone = '-1' 
where left(contacts.phone,3) in (Select timezones.areacode 
                                from timezones 
                                where timezones.timezone = '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change where part like :
....

```
where left(...) in (select ...... )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that probably there are more than 1 row in timezones that have t`imezone column = '-1'`

You can use a `Join` here

```
update contacts join timezones on left(contacts.phone,3) = timezones.areacode and timezones.timezone = '-1'
set contacts.timezone = '-1';
```

It will match the areacodes with the phones, and in that cases will update with `'-1'`